# How can i get the Audio file that the user picks

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I would want to get a handle to the actual audio file that i pick. For selecting the audio file, i have an intent that looks like this :

```
Intent audioIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(audioIntent , 0);
```

It allows me to get a popup to pick audio files from but how can i get the file that i have picked ?

In the case of images, i have :

```
bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), intent.getData());
```

Is there something similar for audio files ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, AUDIO_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);

if (requestCode == AUDIO_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
          String path = _getRealPathFromURI(context, intent.getData());
          File audio = new File(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private String _getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: note: `intent` in the code above is the Intent data as in `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)`

Answer (score 0):

There should be a similar method for `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, it has a `getContentUri(String)` that returns a `Uri` object. See if that helps.

[Link to Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html)